# Condition using char in Scheme

Tags: if-statement, char, scheme, racket

I'm trying to use char as a condition in my if-else statement but it seems the condition only can accept integer input.

This is my code:

```
(display "Presenter - R \nParticipant - P")

(define (option)
  (define r(read))
(cond
  ((= r R )
   (display "Presenter: \nLocal - RM1272\nInternational - RM1474"))
  ((= r P )
   (display "Participant: \nLocal - RM795\nInternational - RM800"))
))
```

Output:

```
Presenter - R 
Participant - P
> (option)
R
. . =: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: r
```

Comment: `=` works only for numbers.  You need to find a predicate which works for more general types.

Comment: Jus use `equal?`

Comment: using `equal?` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The result of your `(read)` is the symbol R, which is neither character nor identifier.
You can also only use `=` for comparing numbers.

```
> (define r (read))
R
> r
'R
> (equal? r R)
. . R: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
> (equal? r #\R)
#f
> (equal? r 'R)
#t
```

Comment: Then it should display the price whether presenter or participant in an if-else statement. Your coding does come out with any price display at the output.

Comment: This is just an illustration of what's wrong with your assumptions and what you should do instead. You need to apply this knowledge and complete your code yourself.

Comment: And the conditional is an expression, not a statement.